# Is there a method to "listen" or list for users in a Google OAuth flow?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have an app that needs to include the OAuth client and secret in the app. The user will sign in via OAuth, be redirected to localhost, and the app itself will run actions on the user's Google account, then revoke its own access.

I am worried about an attacker being able to do something malicious with that secret. So far I cannot think of anything (other than making an OAuth flow using my app name, but that is fine).

I have not found any API endpoints that would allow for this, but I wanted to double check. Any user data being leaked including emails would be bad.

Comment: 1) Only enable `localhost` while testing on systems you control. 2) Never reveal the `Client Secret` within any application or public source. 3) Review [OAuth 2.0 for Client-side Web Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow) and [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see if the app has other authentication mechanism, other than client secret.
JWT/JWKS is one of them, and this is considered as safe approach. Here the JWT is sent as token which is signed with the private key and JWKS contains the public key to verify the signature, JWKS def also contains other parameters like kid which can be used.

Comment: The app itself doesn't need the user's Google. It needs access for a little bit to set up a Firebase DB for the user and then it revokes its own access. There would be no other authentication mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Online auth ended up being the solution. It returns a bearer token directly and that can be used without needing to share a secret.

Comment: thats what i told in  my last comment as below, JWT is a bearer token.

Comment: Oh, my bad! Sorry for not understanding.